# I'm asked to prove the following problem on Convergence. Though I'm not sure how to apply the correct definitions.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Verify that the sequence $\left\{x_{n}=\frac{n^{2}-1}{3n^{2}-4}\mid1\leq n\leq\infty\right\}$ converges to $\frac{1}{3}$ by using the definition of limit.

I've tried all the available definitions provided by my book. But I just can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. You want to show that there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|\frac{n^2-1}{3n^2-4}-\frac{1}{3}|<\epsilon$. This means you  want to show that there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|\frac{3n^2-3 - 3n^2+4}{9n^2-12}|<\epsilon$. This means you  want to show that there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|\frac{1}{9n^2-12}|<\epsilon$. Pick $N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\frac{1}{\epsilon}+12<9N^2$. Then by $n\geq N$ tells you $\frac{1}{\epsilon}+12<9N^2\leq 9n^2$, implying $|\frac{1}{9n^2-12}|<\epsilon$. This is q.e.d

Comment: This makes so much more sense. I really appreciate it.

Comment: can some people upvote this pls. There's obviously some person who doesnt know enough analysis and thinks this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|x_n-\frac13\right|=\frac13\left|\frac1{3n^2-4}\right|\leqslant\frac1{6n^2}\quad (n\geqslant2)\qquad\&\qquad\frac1{6n^2}\to0$$

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use the Limit Comparison Test if you'd like.  Here is a closely related example to your problem: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesCompTest.aspx

You can also solve this by "inspection".  Note that in this problem, your dominant terms are the n^2 on the top and the 3n^2 on the bottom, so overall, the sequence behaves like n^2/3n^2. From there you can factor out a 1/3 and you're left with (1/3)*(n^2/n^2), which equals (1/3)*1 which equals 1/3.

Certainly this is a less technical explanation than the one given by 'mathemagician' (who did a nice job), but hopefully this is more layman's terms.  Hope this helps!